# I want to dynamically take inputs from a couple of views. How do I do that?

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

So, I have an activity in my app where I need to take in the number of tickets for different ticket classes that are retrieved from the backend. The number of ticket classes is also variable. How do I take the user input in this case? Each time the countdown_btn or countup_btn is pressed, I need to update an array that holds the number of tickets the user has chosen. How do I do this when the number of ticket classes itself is dynamic?

If the button 'pledge' is clicked, I want to take the respective inputs from each of the views here and somehow communicate it to the next activity using intent.

My app's code:

```
public class RewardsAndPledgeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference mRewardsRef;
    RecyclerView rewards_list;
    String Artcall_id;
    String reward_id[];
    Integer counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_rewards);


        /* -------- Obtain the Event ID of the item that the user has selected on the RecyclerView ------*/
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Artcall_id  = intent.getStringExtra("Artcall_id");
        /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        mRewardsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rewards").child(Artcall_id);
        rewards_list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reward_list);

        rewards_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rewards_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Reward_List, RewardsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Reward_List, RewardsViewHolder>(
                Reward_List.class,
                R.layout.single_reward_item_layout,
                RewardsAndPledgeActivity.RewardsViewHolder.class,
                mRewardsRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final RewardsViewHolder viewHolder, Reward_List model, int position) {
                final String reward_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                viewHolder.setReward_ticket_amount_txt(model.getReward_ticket_amount_txt());
                viewHolder.setReward_ticket_amount_class_name(model.getReward_ticket_amount_class_name());
                viewHolder.setReward_ticket_class_desc(model.getReward_ticket_class_desc());

                viewHolder.countdown_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Integer current_ticket_count = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.ticket_counter.getText().toString());
                        if(current_ticket_count >0 ) {
                            viewHolder.ticket_counter.setText(String.valueOf(current_ticket_count - 1));
                        }
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.countup_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Integer current_ticket_count = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.ticket_counter.getText().toString());
                        viewHolder.ticket_counter.setText(String.valueOf(current_ticket_count + 1));

                    }
                });


            }
        };

            rewards_list.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }


}
```

My database:
[image]

Image of the activity:
[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: I just added it!

Comment: Perfect. Now please indicate what is the result that you expect.

Comment: I just added an image. Do you understand my question better now?

Comment: No, according to your database structure, I want know what you expect to get. Please give me a concrete example.

Comment: I want to be able to write how many tickets the user has bought for which all ticket classes at some place in the database. I'm having trouble getting the input because the number of classes and the names of the classes are different for each event.

Comment: According to ypur screenshot, give me a concrete example. How many tickets?

Comment: But that's determined by the user! Could be any number of tickets in any category!